# Perl S3 Multipart Upload using Net::Amazon::S3

Tags: perl, amazon-s3

I want to upload some large binary files to a private S3 bucket using Perl.

I implemented a test script for a simple file upload using the [Net::Amazon::S3](https://metacpan.org/release/Net-Amazon-S3) library.

My perl script looks like this:

```
use Net::Amazon::S3;

# S3 Config
$S3_ACCESS_KEY = "xxxxxx";
$S3_SECRET_KEY = "xxxxx";
$S3_HOST = "xxxxx";
$S3_BUCKET = "mybucket";

# Open S3 Connection
$s3 = Net::Amazon::S3->new(
    {
        aws_access_key_id     => $S3_ACCESS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key => $S3_SECRET_KEY,
        host                  => $S3_HOST,
        secure                => 0,
    }
);

# Create and open Bucket
$bucket = $s3->add_bucket(
    { bucket => $S3_BUCKET }
);

$bucket->add_key_filename(
    "myfile.gz", # Object name on S3
    "/tmp/myfile.gz", # Local filename
    { 'content_type'=> 'application/gzip' },
);
```

This works well for small files, but for large files (several GB), I have to implement a multi-part upload.

Unfortunately, the documentation on this library is rather succint.

I think I needs to implement methods like *InitiateMultipartUpload*, *PutPart* and *CompleteMultipartUpload* but I am not sure how to use them.

Is there an example of a multipart upload using this library or any other   option for doing this with Perl?

Comment: For AWS with perl please try [Paws - Perl AWS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Paws::S3). I have used this module for EC2, S3, RDS etc and was very happy and never had to miss [boto](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs say...

> *Note: This is the legacy interface, please check out Net::Amazon::S3::Client instead.*

Looking at [Net::Amazon::S3::Client](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Amazon::S3::Client)...

> *The Net::Amazon::S3::Client, Net::Amazon::S3::Client::Bucket and Net::Amazon::S3::Client::Object classes are designed after years of usage to be easy to use for common tasks.*

And [Net::Amazon::S3::Client::Object](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Amazon::S3::Client::Object) has [some information about multipart uploads](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Amazon::S3::Client::Object#initiate_multipart_upload).

```
#initiate a new multipart upload for this object
my $object = $bucket->object(
  key         => 'massive_video.avi'
);
my $upload_id = $object->initiate_multipart_upload;

...

#add a part to a multipart upload
my $put_part_response = $object->put_part(
   upload_id      => $upload_id,
   part_number    => 1,
   value          => $chunk_content,
);
my $part_etag = $put_part_response->header('ETag');

...

#complete a multipart upload
$object->complete_multipart_upload(
  upload_id       => $upload_id,
  etags           => [$etag_1, $etag_2],
  part_numbers    => [$part_number_1, $part_number2],
);
```

Hopefully with this and clues from [the Multipart Upload REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingRESTAPImpUpload.html) you can take it from there.