# Net::Amazon::S3::Client Produces Error on initiate_multipart_upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, perl, amazon-s3

There seems to be some issue triggering `initiate_multipart_upload` in Net::Amazon::S3::Client. When I do so, I receive the error:

```
Can't call method "findvalue" on an undefined value at /usr/local/share/perl5/Net/Amazon/S3/Operation/Object/Upload/Create/Response.pm line 17.
```

I can do a normal `put` on the object without any error. All else seems to be functional, with lists of the bucket working, etc. Here is a code snippet of what I'm trying:

```
use Net::Amazon::S3;
our $s3 = Net::Amazon::S3->new({
    aws_access_key_id  => $config{'access_key_id'},
    aws_secret_access_key => $config{'access_key'},
    retry => 1
});

our $s3client = Net::Amazon::S3::Client->new( s3 => $s3 );  

my $bucket = $s3client->bucket( name => $bucketName ); 

my $s3object = $bucket->object( key => 'test.txt' );
print 'Key: ' . $s3object->key;

my $uploadId = $s3object->initiate_multipart_upload;
```

Net::Amazon::S3::Client doesn't object to creating the bucket or the object.

I've been able to initialize a multipart upload using the `Paws::S3` library on this bucket just fine. I switched to `Net::Amazon::S3::Client` since `Paws::S3` seems to get stuck at around the 21% mark of uploading my multipart file.

Comment: See also [Perl S3 Multipart Upload using Net::Amazon::S3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56261523/2173773)

Comment: @HåkonHægland that's actually the thread that tipped me off to the existence of `Net::Amazon::S3::Client`, the newer API, which is what I'm trying to use. Unfortunately, it the answer in that question that is not working so far.

Comment: *"Can't call method "findvalue" on an undefined value"* : I am able to reproduce that error now. I will try to figure out what is going on

Comment: @HåkonHægland thanks so much for your help! I'm glad it is not just me!

Comment: Found some clues, see: https://github.com/rustyconover/net-amazon-s3/issues/124#issuecomment-1352547767

Comment: @HåkonHægland thank you! I overrode the function in my code with the new code you proposed and it did indeed work. I ended up finding that the function to complete the upload also failed thereafter in Net::Amazon::S3, alas, but at least it can get through the main process now.