# Amazon S3 Multipart Upload Fails at 21% in Paws::S3, Net::Amazon::S3::Client and Amazon::S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, perl, amazon-s3

I've been attempting to do a simple, but large file upload to S3 in Perl. Using `Paws::S3`, `Net::Amazon::S3::Client` and `Amazon::S3`, it fails at around 21% of the chunks being uploaded -- the first chunks go fine, but no matter how small or large of chunks I go with, at approximately that percentage of them, it fails. I've run into problems trying to use `Net::Amazon::S3::Client` more generally, but have kludged my way past the issue [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74795610/netamazons3client-produces-error-on-initiate-multipart-upload) for now.

I'm suspecting this is an S3 issue at this point, since I'm using two completely separate Perl libraries to attempt the upload, although perhaps both libraries have the same flaw. The `Paws::S3` library simply pauses for a long time, outputs so much gibberish that it crashes my Terminal app and dies. `Net::Amazon::S3::Client` at least gives a bit more of a meaningful error output:

```
Subroutine Net::Amazon::S3::Client::Object::put_part redefined at ftBackupPaws.pl line 136, <FH> line 14.
Progress:  21% [=======================================                                                                                                                                                     ]ETA  12:05500: write failed:  at /usr/local/share/perl5/Net/Amazon/S3/Error/Handler/Confess.pm line 35.
    Net::Amazon::S3::Error::Handler::Confess::handle_error(Net::Amazon::S3::Error::Handler::Confess=HASH(0x55b8d529af68), Net::Amazon::S3::Operation::Object::Upload::Part::Response=HASH(0x55b8d5ca7d50)) called at /usr/local/share/perl5/Net/Amazon/S3.pm line 393
    Net::Amazon::S3::_perform_operation(Net::Amazon::S3=HASH(0x55b8d55a6fb0), "Net::Amazon::S3::Operation::Object::Upload::Part", "error_handler", Net::Amazon::S3::Error::Handler::Confess=HASH(0x55b8d529af68), "bucket", "MyBucketName", "part_number", 21, ...) called at /usr/local/share/perl5/Net/Amazon/S3/Client.pm line 109
    Net::Amazon::S3::Client::_perform_operation(Net::Amazon::S3::Client=HASH(0x55b8d044cab0), "Net::Amazon::S3::Operation::Object::Upload::Part", "bucket", "MyBucketName", "headers", HASH(0x55b8d601b8c0), "part_number", 21, ...) called at /usr/local/share/perl5/Net/Amazon/S3/Client/Bucket.pm line 197
    Net::Amazon::S3::Client::Bucket::_perform_operation(Net::Amazon::S3::Client::Bucket=HASH(0x55b8d55a6fc8), "Net::Amazon::S3::Operation::Object::Upload::Part", "key", "multipart1", "part_number", 21, "headers", HASH(0x55b8d601b8c0), ...) called at /usr/local/share/perl5/Net/Amazon/S3/Client/Object.pm line 520
    Net::Amazon::S3::Client::Object::_perform_operation(Net::Amazon::S3::Client::Object=HASH(0x55b8d55a17b0), "Net::Amazon::S3::Operation::Object::Upload::Part", "upload_id", "BmDoBE8OdS8aUMUpP5m3jf9ltt7NmTiWuou01ODeW3YZzloElL3EnUcdApIX_"..., "part_number", 21, "headers", HASH(0x55b8d601b8c0), ...) called at ftBackupPaws.pl line 133
    main::__ANON__(Net::Amazon::S3::Client::Object=HASH(0x55b8d55a17b0), "upload_id", "theUploadId"..., "part_number", 21, "value", "\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}"...) called at ftBackupPaws.pl line 164
```

The code that is presently doing the upload is, as I said, a bit of a kludge. `Net::Amazon::S3::Client` seems to have a bug that prevents it from initializing a multipart upload, so to get started, I used `aws-cli` to create get an upload id and hard coded it for the time being, just to try to assess how everything else worked. Here's the `Paws::S3` version since it is less kludgy, but, again, they fail at the same point.

```
use Paws;
use Paws::Credential::Explicit;
use POSIX;
use Term::ProgressBar;

our $paws = Paws->new(config => {
  credentials => Paws::Credential::Explicit->new(
    access_key => $config{'access_key_id'},
    secret_key => $config{'access_key'}
  )
});


our $pawsS3 = Paws->service('S3', credentials => Paws::Credential::Explicit->new(
            access_key => $config{'access_key_id'},
            secret_key => $config{'access_key'}), 
        region => 'us-east-1');

my $CreateMultipartUploadOutput = $pawsS3->CreateMultipartUpload(
    'Bucket' => $bucketName,
    'Key'    => 'backup/daily/2022-11-13/myaccount.tar.gz'
);  

my $filename = "/backup/2022-12-13/accounts/myaccount.tar.gz";
my $size = -s $filename;  
my $fiveMeg = (1024*1024*500);
my $parts = ceil($size / $fiveMeg);
my @manifest;

open(my $file, "/backup/2022-12-13/accounts/myaccount.tar.gz") or die("Error reading file, stopped");

my $progress = Term::ProgressBar->new({name  => 'Progress',
                                        count => $parts,
                                        ETA   => 'linear', 
                                        remove => 1 });

for (my $i = 0; $i <= $parts; $i++) {
    my $chunk;
    my $offset = $i * $fiveMeg;

    read($file, $chunk, $fiveMeg, $offset);
    my $UploadPartOutput = $pawsS3->UploadPart(
        'Body'       => $chunk,
        'Bucket'     => $bucketName,
        'Key'        => 'backup/daily/2022-11-13/myaccount.tar.gz',
        'PartNumber' => $i + 1,
        'UploadId'   => $CreateMultipartUploadOutput->UploadId
    );

    push (@manifest, { 'ETag' => $UploadPartOutput->ETag, 'PartNumber' => $i +1 });

    $progressBarUpdate = $progress->update($i);
    say STDOUT 'Chunk ' . $i . '/' . $parts;
}

close(FILE); 


    my $CompleteMultipartUploadOutput = $pawsS3->CompleteMultipartUpload(
        'Bucket'     => $bucketName,
        'Key'        => 'backup/daily/2022-11-13/myaccount.tar.gz',
        'MultipartUpload' => {
                'Parts' => \@manifest
            },
        'UploadId' => $CreateMultipartUploadOutput->UploadId
    );

    # Results:
    use Data::Dumper;
    say STDOUT Dumper $CompleteMultipartUploadOutput;
```

I can provide the other code base, too, if that's helpful.

**Update (December 15, 2022):** So it must have something to do with the API and not S3 itself. To try to test it further, I modified my script to output the 18 chunks rather than upload them. I then tried to use the `aws` console app to to a multipart upload:

```
aws s3api create-multipart-upload --bucket mybucket --key 'multipart1'

aws s3api upload-part --bucket mybucket --key 'multipart1' --part-number 1 --body part0 --upload-id  [ID GOES HERE]
aws s3api upload-part --bucket mybucket --key 'multipart1' --part-number 2 --body part1 --upload-id  [ID GOES HERE]
# ....
```

I went well beyond the stopping point in the Perl API and each upload successfully received an etag. So there's something in both `Paws::S3` and `Net::Amazon::S3::Client` causing a disruption at around 2GB of uploads that *doesn't* happen in was-cli.

**Updated (December 15, 2022):** I tried `Amazon::S3` and the result was the same: when it has uploaded 21%, it fails with:

```
Amazon::S3: Amazon responded with 500 write failed:   at /usr/local/share/perl5/Amazon/S3/Bucket.pm line 418 thread 2.
```

I also tried iterating so that the program would hit the "troublemaking" bucket that appears at the 21% mark *first*. In doing so, the upload still failed at having uploaded 21% of the chunks -- so the failure seems to be tied somehow to how much stuff is being uploaded rather than it being something corrupt in a particular chunk.

Also, I tried implementing threading thinking maybe the upload was timing out. But queuing up the work into multiple threads didn't solve anything other than getting me to the failure point faster.

Comment: What is the total size of the file you are uploading, and how many bytes are successfully being uploaded?

Comment: @tobyink It's a 9.6 GB file. I don't have a way (that I've discovered, at least) to get the exact number of bytes sent before failure, but at the 21% mark, it would be right around 2 GB that gets uploaded before failure. Which, incidentally, is about the same place it stops when doing a single big upload, as opposed to a multipart upload using Net::Amazon::S3.

Comment: Added comparison with AWS cli, above.

Comment: I suspect there could be a memory management issue at play: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74809513/perl-memory-management-problem-with-object-and-large-file-processing